# Can not connect to database : Mongoose/MongoDB, virtual box

Tags: virtualbox

## Context

A MongoDB database runs on an `Ubuntu` Virtual Machine (VM).

An `express` server app serves a directory on my host machine (Windows 10).

This directory is shared with the VM.

## Issue

I am trying to launch my `express` app locally without success.

On VM side, connecting to the database via the mongo shell works normally.

On the host side, i just used npm start to launch the app.

Do I need to do something else so my machine host/the app can communicate with the db in the VM ?

I have tried :

- https://serverfault.com/questions/225155/virtualbox-how-to-set-up-networking-so-both-host-and-guest-can-access-internet
  and
- https://2buntu.com/articles/1513/accessing-your-virtualbox-guest-from-your-host-os/
  ...but it didn't work.

I get this error :

> [error with npm start](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HKk0l.jpg)

Thank you for you help

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are here mixing two things :

- Connection to a remote database host on a Virtual Machine
- Running an application on a Virtual Machine that communicates to a local database on the Virtual Machine too

From what you explains, it seems that your setup looks like this :

```
+-------------------------+                      +------------------------+
|                             |                      |                           |
| Windows 10 host machine  | --  Shared folder -|    Virtual machine      |
|                             |      application   |    MongoDB running      |
|                             |                      |                           |
+-------------------------+                      +------------------------+
```

- When you run `npm run main` on your host machine, the application needs to connect to the remote database using Virtual Machine network adresse. Sharing a folder with the Virtual Machine has no report with reaching database.
- When you run `npm run main` on your local machine, you can connect using `localhost`
  or Virtual machinbe network adresse.

---

Your issue is not related to `npm` or `mongodb` but on your Virtual Machine connection setup.

**If the application runs on Windows 10**, the easiest way to setup your Virtual Machine network and connect to database is to set `Bridge adpater` on the VirtualBox's VM settings.
[image]

Then, setting `dhcp` on the main network interface of your Ubuntu machine will provides you an address.

Edit **`/etc/networking/interfaces`** then restart network using `sudo /etc/init.d/networking restart`

```
# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# The primary network interface
auto enp0s3
iface enp0s3 inet dhcp
```

Use provided `enp0s3` inet address to connect to your VM's database. To get the proivided adress, use `ip addr` on a shell.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
I am still a beginner, so i understand the general idea but i don't understand exactly how to do it.

On the VirtualBox's VM settings -> network tab -> adapter 2 : I clicked enable network adapter and chose "bridged adapter". I left the name by default : "realtek wireless...". 
Adapter 1 is (by default) attached to NAT.

I don't understand this sentence : "Then, setting dhcp [...]. Use this address to connect to your VM's database."

(since I modified the vm parameters, I can't connect anymore to Internet...).

Comment: Before trying, I just wanted to check something. I wrote the details in an "answer message" since the comment length is limited.

Answer (score 0):

@user7364588

i don't have the etc/networking/interfaces but etc/network/interfaces with only this message inside :

```
# ifupdown has been replaced by netplan(5) on this system.  See
# /etc/netplan for current configuration.
# To re-enable ifupdown on this system, you can run:
#    sudo apt install ifupdown
```

Should I still apply your advice or use netplan ?

Inside netplan, I have a file 50-cloud-init.yaml containing

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    eth0:
      dhcp4: true
      dhcp6: false
      optional: true
      nameservers:
        addresses: [4.2.2.1, 4.2.2.2, 208.67.220.220]
```

ip addr :

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 08:00:27:e3:9f:67 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 10.0.2.15/24 brd 10.0.2.255 scope global dynamic eth0
       valid_lft 85581sec preferred_lft 85581sec
    inet6 fe80::a00:27ff:fee3:9f67/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

Comment: It seems like `netplan` is already configuring the network.  An inet ip adress should be set, check with `ip addr` command line into a shell. As long as you do not tell this command result, it should be hard to say if network is correctly setup.

Comment: I ended up losing my internet connexion trying to bridge, so I had to reinitialize my computer... The installation is the same, the problem persists. I just did not try to bridge yet since I don't want to loose my Internet connexion again.